# Hard Yeshivish phrases to translate

Tags: talmud-gemara, hebrew, aramaic, language, transliteration

Does anyone ever have trouble finding good English translations of certain yeshivish phrases, especially when in conversation with someone who would not understand the original?

Post your favorite phrases and English translations below.

"l'mai nafka mina?" -> "What is the practical difference?"

"kal v'chomer" -> "all the more so"

"dafka" -> ?? I always want to say this in conversation but don't know how.

"mamash" -> ditto

Comment: see http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1568216149

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: @YeZ http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/959/what-is-our-attitude-to-list-questions

Comment: @Scimonster I wasn't asking _altz_ list (see what I did there?).  I was asking _altz_ its _etzem shaychus_ to the _sugya_ of this site.  I.e. is this about Judaism?

Comment: What about Lichoira

Comment: Don't forget that despite the *patach*, "kal vachomer" is sometimes pronounced "kol vachoymer"

Comment: @YeZ I'm not sure what "yeshivish" means but, based on that word's etymology, I'd guess this question is about Judaism.

Comment: @msh210 why would it be any better than a question about Yiddish, which has a _very_ Jewish etymology?

Comment: @YeZ Yiddish is, in terms of its name's etymology, the language of Jews. Yeshivish, by the same token, is the language of yeshivas.

Comment: Can we add "Davka lav"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> "I *davka* haven't seen that movie."

I *purposely* haven't seen that movie.

or

I *specifically have NOT* seen that movie.

---

> "He doesn't eat peanut butter, *b'shita*"

He doesn't eat peanut butter, *on principle.*  (or "as a matter of principle").

---

"Mamash" in proper Hebrew usage should translate as "tangible"; that works sometimes.

> "He's *mamash* the biggest *masmid* I've ever seen"

He's *seriously* / *honestly* the most diligent student I've ever seen.

Or if we [allow a sacrifice to colloquial usage and disregard proper grammar](http://xkcd.com/725/),

He's *literally* the most diligent student I've ever seen.

Unless you're a [valley girl,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valley_girl) (California yeshivish?) in which case it's:

He's like, *totally* the most diligent dude I've, like, ever seen.

---

> "*Aderaba* / *pum fakert*, summer is the BEST time for holding by cholent."

*On the contrary* (or *au contraire*), summer is the best time to be in the mood for stew.

(The prescriptivist squad tells me this is supposed to be *punkt fakert*, but I'm writing them as I normally hear them.)

---

> *"Shaychus?!"*
>   (Best asked with a bewildered look on one's face.)

"*Relevance?!*"

---

> "He is *takke* matir"

He *in fact* allows it ; or *As a matter of fact*, he allows it.

---

> "He *lahadam'd* the whole parsha"

He *flat-out denied* the entire incident.

> "The *gantza inyan* is a *shtickel shvach*"

The *whole notion* is a *bit weak*.

> "Is it *davka* this *maysa*, or is he *stam azoi* a *macha'os-dika* guy?"

Is it *specifically* this *episode*, or is he *more generally* a *protest-loving kind of* person?

> "His *svora* is (*mamash*) *gishmack*."

His *logical argument* is (*totally*) *cool*.

> "Was there ever *a havamina* (*hava amina*) that the shidduch was shayach?  Or that he'd become a chosson?"

Was there ever *the slightest notion* that they'd make a feasible couple?  Or that he'd get engaged?

> "For me you opened the door?  *Shkoyach*!"

You opened the door for me?  *Thank you!*

> "Is there *an inyan of* wearing a hat and jacket?"

Is it *of halachic value* to wear a hat and jacket?

Comment: Actually, it's not "pum fakert," it's "punkt fahrkert," with "punkt" being the Yiddish word for "exactly." If you are Galatzianish/Chassidish, it's pronounced "pinkt."

Comment: +1 for: "Unless you're a valley girl, (California yeshivish?) in which case it's:

He's like, totally the most diligent dude I've, like, ever seen. "

Comment: The word "takke" I think is better translated as "indeed". Translating "in fact" to Yeshivish would yield "In emess'n arein."

Comment: What's "lahadam'd" in "He lahadam'd the whole parsha"? Can you write the Hebrew? I can't figure out how to pronounce it or where it comes from.

Comment: @Mark, Lamed-Heh-Dalet-Mem. If I claim you owe me money, you can respond *Lo Hayu Dvarim MeOlam* -- no such thing ever happened. Abbreviated "lahadam." Hence, "to lahadam."

Comment: You deserve a +1 just for the edit summaries, forget the actual edits.

Answer (score 8):

The definitive work on this topic is [Frumspeak](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568216149), by Chaim Weiser. You might also find the Wikipedia entry on [Yeshivish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeshivish) to be enlightening, and perhaps humorous too!

Comment: The book is interesting and humorous too. Though as a person who has studied linguistics, I question the author's premise that Yeshivish is a language.

Answer (score 7):

> "*Beseder*"

*OK*

> "*Gevaldik*"

*Great*

> "It was *bizyonos*"

It was *embarrassing* (*Givaldiger bizyonos* would be *greatly embarrassing.* Are you catching on?)

> "I can't be *masig* why he'd do such a thing."

I can't *fathom* why he'd do such a thing.

> "*Lchoyra* it was because it wasn't *shayach*."

*Presumably*, it was because it wasn't *possible*.

> "*Meheicha Teisa* you should get the *shteller*?"

(lit.) *Where did you get it from* (or - loosely translated) *Why would you think* you should get the *position*?

> It's *gradder* a *gantz feiner* yeshiva.

It's *actually/in fact* a *pretty good* yeshiva.

Comment: For "not shayach", I prefer "infeasible" to "impossible."

Answer (score 4):

The yiddish word *bavoren/bavorenin* as in:

Rashi already *bavorened* that *kasha* (question).

it would translate to:

Rashi *preempted* that question (by stating something that resolves the potential question, without actually specifying that he intends to answer a question).

(In my Yiddish dictionary, it's translated as "a security" - in this context, it means that one secured himself against a particular question by preempting it.)

Comment: See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9242/what-is-the-english-translation-of-the-yiddish-word-%D7%91%D7%90%D7%95%D7%95%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%9F

Answer (score 3):

The cool speak for see you later is shpayterz. A bit like laterz. Shpayter is yiddish for later. Hence proper yiddish gangster talk.

Also, the traditional greeting is "A giten" to which you can respond "A giten", "A besseren" or if you're feeling a little peeved, "An ergeren". Which transalate as "A good one", "A better one" and "A worse one" respectively.

Comment: Choimshy, welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks for this contribution! Please consider registering your account, to help the site keep track of your contributions no matter where you log in from.

Answer (score 3):

The [review](http://www.amazon.com/review/R1KJZSHCOXYVBX/ref=cm_cr_dp_title?ie=UTF8&ASIN=1568216149&channel=detail-glance&nodeID=283155&store=books) of the Book [Frumspeak](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568216149) has a good example of many untranslated words so far:

> This is a gevaldike sefer, and I got asach hanaa from it. The etzem dictionary is gantz useful for talmidim of the shprach, and it's also geshmak to stam read through, which is a big toeles.
>
> The hakdoma, on the metzius of yeshivish, is tief, and the other shticklach at the haschala (including a translation of Hamlet's soliloquy) are peledik.
> I mamish hold of this sefer.

In English that would read something like:

This is an amazing book, and I got a lot of benefit from it. The actual dictionary is very useful for students of the language, and it's also enjoyable to just plain read through, which is a big worthwhile accomplishment.

The preface, on the reality of Yeshivish is deep and the other small discussions at the beginning (including a translation of Hamlet's soliloquy) are amazing. I really approve of* this book.

*This one is an interesting case, as it is basically transforming the Yiddish to English but still keeping the Yiddish idiom; "hold of" is either approve of, follow or agree with.

(This translation prefers to keep the sentence structure rather than be grammatically proper).

Comment: Now I can't get [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uqs_ZMjG7zI) out of my head :-(

Comment: I had that song in my head even before you posted it. :P

Answer (score 3):

> *Le'maiseh*, it's not *mistaber*.

*For all practical intents and purposes*, it doesn't *make sense*

> It's a *shver* *sugya* to discuss with my *shver*.

It's a *difficult* *topic* to discuss with my *father in law*.

> *B'kitzur*, the whole *matzav* is *nisht poshut*.

*In short*, the whole *situation* is *not simple*.

> *Altz* list question, I think this question is on topic.  *Ubber*, *altz* related to Judaism, I'm not so sure.

*In terms of* (or as a function of) list question, I think this question is on topic.  *But*, *in terms of* related to Judaism, I'm not so sure.

Comment: *Ich veis nisht*, but I'd *taina* that it's *mashma* from your *lushen* that you made a *tzu shtel* between *shver* and *shver*, that they're *takka* the *zelba zach*. (*Grahde*, that's a *bavuste tzu shtel altz* the homophony). *Be'emes*, there's no *kesher zu eitzel zu*. *Avada* you should delete this *altz shidduchim*, otherwise Google cache will *zicher bahlt chap* it *ois*. +1

Comment: @Fred _Boruch Hashem_ my _shver_ holds _shtark_ that the internet is a _treife zach_ and won't know about this whole _shakla v'tarya_.