# What is the English translation of the Yiddish word באווארן?

Tags: yiddish, translation

I'm trying to figure out a good way to say the Yiddish word באווארן in English. **We used this a lot in Yeshiva, usually in the context of "to באווארן a question"**.

To explain:

A statement would be structured in such a way that it answers and negates a question before it is asked.

@IsaacMoses described it thusly below: `A statement that includes information that undermines a challenge you might otherwise pose to that statement.`

An example:

I could say that rice takes 20 minutes to cook. You would then ask, "what about brown rice, it takes 40 minutes?" I would then answer I meant white rice.

Or I could say that white rice takes 20 minutes to cook. By adding the word "white" to the statement, I made it clear that I wasn't referring to brown rice, and thus your question about brown rice was answered and negated before you asked it. By phrasing the statement that way, I באווארנט your question about brown rice.

Google Translate offers "`guard`", "`watch`", or "`guarding`", but none of that sounds right in this context.

The closest I've thought of is "`anticipate`", as in "The statement was structured in such a way to anticipate your question".

Other possibilities that come to mind are "`obviate`", "`preempt`", "`negate`", "`address`", "`precede`", but none of those sound right.

There must be an english word for this.

Comment: what about 'protect' or 'secure'?  As in you protect yourself from a question. Or I secured myself from your question.

Comment: @avi: It's closer to the dictionary definition, but it doesn't quite sound right when saying it.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/hard-yeshivish-phrases-to-translate/1733

Comment: In the subtitles to the Lubavitcher Rebbe's sichos, this is translated as "foresee." I think it's good

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like "preemptively address".

Comment: user795, Welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for this suggestion! Please consider editing [your profile](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/795/user795) to give yourself a name.

Answer (score 8):

"Anticipate" is exactly the word I would use. "Preempt" takes second place.

(These might not be *exact* translations -- but hey, did you ever try to translate the word *mechutan*?)

Answer (score 1):

My Yiddish dictionary has bavornt as "secure", "proof".

You can use it as a suffix as in vaser-bavornt, or follow it with kegn to say proof against...

Comment: I was thinking that maybe the word 'prevent' would work while fitting in with the dictionary definition. As in: "The wording of my statement prevented you from asking a question". Kind of like you could say 'waterproof' could mean "secure against water damage", or "water damage will be prevented".

Answer (score 1):

"I'm trying to figure out a good way to say the Yiddish word באווארן in English. We used this a lot in Yeshiva, usually in the context of "to באווארן a question".

to Forestall.. or preempt

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is an English phrase that seems very similar to this, although it is often misused:

> To beg the question.

For the full and proper explanation, see this question on English.SE - [What does the phrase “Begging the question” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/305/what-does-the-phrase-begging-the-question-mean/306#306) :

> a type of logical fallacy in which the proposition to be proved is assumed implicitly or explicitly in the premise.

(Though I guess the "Jewish twist" here, would be inverting the phraseology... Still, I think it's close enough).

Comment: I don't think this is the same thing as Menachem described. He didn't describe a logical fallacy; he described a statement that includes information that undermines a challenge you might otherwise pose to that statement, which seems to be a logically sound device.

Comment: Wait, I realized I'm not sure about something here (I'm not familiar with the term...): is the `באווארנט` apply to the `"what about brown rice, it takes 40 minutes?"`, or to the `"white rice takes 20 minutes to cook"`?

Comment: @Isaac, I re-re-read it again, and realized I had it backwards (I think...)

Comment: @AviD: the באווארנט applies to the "what about brown rice, it takes 40 minutes?". By adding the word "white" to the question, I made it clear that I wasn't referring to brown rice, and thus your question about brown rice was answered and negated before you asked it.

Comment: @Menachem, so the bavaranting is saying "white rice", or asking about the brown rice?

Comment: @AviD, if I understand correctly, saying "white rice" to begin with bavarns the brown rice challenge, and the brown rice challenge is thus bavarnt (or, in contemporary slang pattern, bavarn'd).

Comment: @AviD: I mistyped, here's take two: I made a statement that white rice takes 20 minutes to cook. By adding the word "white" to the statement, I made it clear that I wasn't referring to brown rice, and thus your question about brown rice was addressed and negated before you asked it. By phrasing the statement that way, I באווארנט your question about brown rice. I'm obviously not speaking about brown rice, since I specifically said white rice. -- so the bavarning is done by saying "white rice".

Comment: @Menachem Aah, now I understand. So yes, this is not the same as begging the question, but I'll just leave this answer here for the discussion. On the other hand, I dont understand why there's a specific word for it: I just call it `"being specific"` ;)

Comment: @AviD: Which leads to another question, how do you say "M'Dayek" in English (As in, we can be M'Dayek from the words of Rashi that he holds such-and-such)?

Comment: @Menachem how about "extrapolate from the specificity"?