# Davka, Mamash, and B'Emet

Tags: hebrew, translation

When speaking in primarily English but using the words Davka, Mamash, or B'Emet:

How do you define them into English?

What is the difference between them?

How do you use each one properly?

Comment: [On-topic?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)

Comment: Why did someone vote to close as non-constructive?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/hard-yeshivish-phrases-to-translate

Comment: @yydl Presumable because this site is not usually for hebrew language questions. Although there are many such questions sprinkled around.

Comment: That would make it off-topic. It's still a valid question - just not for *this* site.

Answer (score 5):

- *Davka* = "Specifically, Precisely, Deliberately; Purposely; In fact, Actually"  (See [here](http://elephant.org.il/translate/davka.html) for more possibilities.)
- *Mamash* = "Really, Very much; Precisely, Specifically, Exactly, In fact, Truly (in a **colloquial** or **metaphorical** sense)" (However, this word is primarily used for exclamatory emphasis, and can be dropped from the sentence without significantly changing the meaning.)  (See also [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/599145/jewish/How-One-Word-Changed-the-World.htm).)
- *B'Emet* = "Honestly, In truth, In all honesty; Really, Truly (Can also be used as a question); Indeed; Please"

Sources: My knowledge of Hebrew, [Milon Morfix](http://morfix.mako.co.il), Milon Even-Shoshan, [Babylon Translate](http://translation.babylon.com/hebrew/to-english/).

---

See also:

- [Hard Yeshivish phrases to translate](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/hard-yeshivish-phrases-to-translate)
- [Frumspeak Dictionary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568216149)
- [Yiddish words in English](http://www.hebrew4christians.com/Glossary/Yiddish_Words/yiddish_words.html)

Comment: Davka is often also used as "in spite", "to spite", and "despite". Even though those are not really equivalent... "Davka" is one of those uniquely Israeli words that dont translate well to other cultures, like chutzpa.

Comment: Chutzpah = Audacity

Comment: eh, that might be a literal translation, but it loses the particular "feel" of the word. That's why its a popular word even in Hollywood...

Comment: Don't these definitions seem to repeat themselves, so how do I differentiate?

Comment: Like many idioms, there are overlaps.  Knowing when to use one over the other is an art that comes with experience.