# What does "Adderabba" mean?

Tags: words

What is the definition or usual translation for the word "Adderabba"?  I sometimes find it as an interjection in Jewish blogs and forums, so it is not easy to figure out the meaning from the context.  On Mi Yodeya, I found it four times (not counting this question), possibly all written by DoubleAA.

Comment: Mike, I've put this on hold as it is currently a Hebrew-language question without specifically-Jewish context, and that's off-topic here.  If you encountered this word in a Jewish context, please [edit] the question to provide more details and we can reopen.  Thanks.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1733/21

Answer (score 2):

Wikimilon (Hebrew Wiktionary) suggests: On the contrary.

[http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/אדרבה](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%94)

Answer (score 1):

Actually it has two meanings:1. "On the contrary", and 2. "More so".
The literal definition is more so.
you can see a [discussion](http://www.tapuz.co.il/forums2008/viewmsg.aspx?forumid=1072&messageid=156344925#156950441) (hebrew) in the hebrew language forum