# What does the word Dochak mean?

Tags: words, talmud-gemara

When I study gemara with some people, I often heard the sentences "he is dochak", "he's not so dochak". What does this word mean exactly ? I do not find it in the dictionnary.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1731

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word "dochak" means forced (duchka d'sakina, for example, means the pressure (force) applied by a knife).

It usually means that an opinion does not fit so smoothly, either in the reading of the words or in logical follow-through, into the discussion at hand.

Comment: So "it's dochak" means "it does not fit" ? While "he's not dochak" means "it fits into the logic of the sugya"?

Comment: @JOJO "He's not dochak" is a bit of a grammatically liberal use of the word (which isn't so bad when you are using a Hebrew word in an English sentence), but it could mean either that his opinion fits nicely into the words, or that his opinion is logically very reasonable.

Answer (score 5):

דָּחוּק = *dachuk*. This is a Hebrew past participle meaning "strained" or "forced". It can also be used to mean "implausible".

Examples in [Yeshivish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeshivish):

I.

> *That explanation is so* dachuk *!*

is equivalent to

> *That explanation is so forced!*

II.

> *He tried to be* metaretz *Rabbi Akiva Eiger's* kasha *on the Taz, but his* s'vara *was* dachuk.

is equivalent to

> *He tried to resolve Rabbi Akiva Eiger's difficulty with the Taz, but his reasoning was implausible*.